# binding values while looping in constructor CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have decided to use CoffeeScript and i have been trying to convert Node.js module of mine to CoffeeScript. So, here is the code in JS:

```
function Domain(obj){
    var self = this;
    for (var key in obj){
        this[key] = obj[key]; //merge values
    }
}

Domain.prototype.save = function(fn){

}
```

And my attempt to have the same in the CoffeeScript as following:

```
class Domain
  consructor: (obj) ->
    for own key, value of obj
      @key = value

  save: (fn) ->

module.exports  = Domain
```

The following test fails:

```
require('coffee-script');
var should = require('should')
    , Domain = require('../index');

should.exist(Domain);

var domain = new Domain({'attOne':1, 'attTwo':2});

domain.should.have.property('save');
domain.should.have.property('attOne');
domain.should.have.property('attTwo');

domain.save.should.be.an.instanceof(Function);

console.log('All tests passed');
```

The property 'attrOne' and 'attrTwo' is not binding to the Domain class. I have compiled the coffee code by 'coffee -c index.coffee' to see the js code:

```
(function() {
  var Domain,
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

  Domain = (function() {
    function Domain() {}

    Domain.prototype.consructor = function(obj) {
      var key, value, _results;

      _results = [];
      for (key in obj) {
        if (!__hasProp.call(obj, key)) continue;
        value = obj[key];
        _results.push(this.key = value);
      }
      return _results;
    };

    Domain.prototype.save = function(fn) {};

    return Domain;

  })();

  module.exports = Domain;

}).call(this);
```

From the compiled js, i see the '_result' array being generated and returned but never binded to 'this'. How would i bind the array into the class scope to pass the test?Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of CoffeeScript

```
@key = value
```

is not equivalent to the javascript you want

```
this[key] = obj[key];
```

The way `@` works is that it is simply replaced by either `this` or `this.`.  Thus, `@key` compiles to `this.key`.  You should instead use

```
@[key] = value
```

Additionally, you spelled `constructor` wrong (as `consructor`).  In CoffeeScript, `constructor` is a special method that compiles differently from a normal method; if it is spelled wrong, CoffeeScript assumes you want an empty one.

Comment: Thank You. Is there an editor that could helped me in avoiding the misspell?...like coloring it in different color the word 'constructor' so i can catch it or some other way

Comment: @latvian Most editors have various coloring plugins.  I would be surprised if you couldn't find a CoffeeScript plugin for your favorite editor.

Comment: WebStorm is the editor i use. i will look into for CoffeeScript plugin. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
consructor: (obj) ->

Domain.prototype.consructor
```

You are missing a `t`.

([I keep saying that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16640840/14955))

Comment: Yes, generated from a source that is missing a `t`